# Angular 2 *ngFor display component template not working

Tags: templates, angular, ngfor

I have this collection in "results.component.ts":  `results: Result[]`

I would like to iterate over the collection, displaying each result.

I would like to have a seperate component for this called result.component.ts. This is because a result could get complex and large.

What I have so far is not displaying anything. The output html has some commented out template bindings:

```
<div _ngcontent-fud-12="" class="col-sm-8 offset-sm-2 col-md-6 offset-md-3 col-xl-4 
            offset-xl-4">
            <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"
}--><!--template bindings={}--><!--template bindings={}--><!--template bindings={}--><!--template bindings={}--><!--template bindings={}--><!--template bindings={}--><!--template bindings={}--><!--template bindings={}--><!--template bindings={}--><!--template bindings={}-->
        </div>
```

Here is my relevant code:

results.component.html:

```
<div id="results" class="text-uppercase">
    <div id="up-button-row" class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 offset-sm-2 col-md-6 offset-md-3 col-xl-4 
            offset-xl-4">
            <button class="m-x-auto" md-fab [disableRipple]="true" (click)="scrollUp()"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" *ngIf="noResults">
        <div class="col-sm-8 offset-sm-2 col-md-6 offset-md-3 col-xl-4 
            offset-xl-4">
            <h2 class="m-x-auto">No vegan stuff found :-(</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="row" *ngIf="!noResults">
        <div class="col-sm-8 offset-sm-2 col-md-6 offset-md-3 col-xl-4 
            offset-xl-4">
            <div *ngFor="let result of results"><result></result></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

results.component.ts:

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ResultComponent } from './result.component';
import { Result } from '../result'

@Component({
   selector: 'results-div',
   templateUrl: 'app/find-page/results.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['app/find-page/results.component.css' ],
   directives:[ResultComponent]
})
export class ResultsComponent implements AfterViewInit {
   results: Result[];
   noResults: boolean;
   ngAfterViewInit() {
this.scrollDown();
   }

   scrollDown() {
      ScrollToAnchor.goToTargetBottom("#results");
   }

   scrollUp() {
     ScrollToAnchor.goToTarget("#find-page");
   }
}
```

result.component.html:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-2" style="margin-top:20px; padding: 25px;">
   <div class="product-item scale-on-hover" (click)="setCurrentlySelectedProduct()">
      <div [ngStyle]="{background: result.imagePath}" id="image"></div>
      <div id="info">
         <h6 id="brand" class="medium-text">{{brand}}</h6>
         <h6 id="name" class="medium-text">{{name}}</h6>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

result.component.ts:

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Result } from '../result';

@Component({
   selector: 'result',
   templateUrl: 'app/find-page/result.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['app/find-page/result.component.css' ]
})
export class ResultComponent{}
```

How do I pass the result data for 1 result from results.component to result.component.

How do I get the result.component.html to display once for each result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Component({
   selector: 'result',
   templateUrl: 'app/find-page/result.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['app/find-page/result.component.css' ]
})
export class ResultComponent{
  @Input() result;
}
```

```
<div *ngFor="let result of results"><result [result]="result"></result></div>
```

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-2" style="margin-top:20px; padding: 25px;">
   <div class="product-item scale-on-hover" (click)="setCurrentlySelectedProduct()">
      <div [ngStyle]="{background: result.imagePath}" id="image"></div>
      <div id="info">
         <h6 id="brand" class="medium-text">{{result.brand}}</h6>
         <h6 id="name" class="medium-text">{{result.name}}</h6>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need the wrapper `div`, you can have the loop and the binding on the same element (see e.g. https://github.com/textbook/known-for-web/blob/bd6d2bcbc93317015d502e21a8dcf29772b253e1/src/app/actor/actor.component.html#L6)

Comment: Thanks. However, still nothing is displaying in the html output after those changes.

Comment: That's correct. I wasn't sure if this was intentional but you are right, it doesn't look like it.

Comment: You need to update the template of `ResultComponent` to refer to the input variable `result.xxx`. I don't know what `(click)="setCurrentlySelectedProduct()"` is supposed to do.

Comment: @Beniamino_Baggins where are you expecting the `results` to come from? They aren't an `@Input` to the `ResultsComponent` and you show no code to e.g. fetch from an API.

Comment: Yeah I actually updated the ResultComponent template with `result.brand` and `result.name` but still not displaying.

Comment: As @Beniamino_Baggins mentioned we can't know what `result` contains. If it doesn't contain data, then Angular can only do so much. Have you checked the browser console for errors?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I do this: `this.results.results = this.findForm.results;` in a parent component.

Comment: @Beniamino_Baggins then please show that, or maybe try it with a static list to test this. What if you just put `{{ results }}` on the page, what does that show? There are several moving parts here and it's hard to remote debug without all the information you have.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer `results: Result[]` is definitely populated. The `result` gets populated from your solution doesn't it? eg `<result [result]="result"`

Comment: @jonrsharpe Are we questioning if the `results` is populated? Because it is. I figure thats why the html output has all those template bindings near the top of my question. It has 10 template bindings and there are 10 results. I can verify this because they are printed to the console.

Comment: If you add static content to `ResultComponent` like `<div>xxx</div>`, is this shown on the page? If not, then `*ngFor` doesn't create `ResultComponent`s at all. Otherwise it's hard to see what's going on from here.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer static content in the result.component template doesn't show on the page. The result doesn't get created at all. However, `results` is definitely populated.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer those 10 commented out template bindings at the top of my question are relevant. they show that for each `result` in `results`, it's trying to output some html but failing somehow.

Comment: No idea. If you can reproduce in a Plunker (use this Angular2 template https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html - "live example" link) than I can have another look.

Comment: You accepted my answer. Does this mean you could make it work?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer somewhere along the way I changed the `<div *ngFor` to `<template *ngFor` and forgot sorry. It does work now after fixing that. Thank you

Comment: @Beniamino_Baggins then this Q & A is not useful. If someone else comes along with a similar problem, how does this help? If you just made a typo then: a) it's not reflected in the question, thus no [mcve]; and b) the binding shown here doesn't actually solve the problem. Please [edit] the question, or consider deleting it entirely.

Comment: @jonrsharpe This answer was the solution to the problem. I did try the code in my question and it did not work. I changed it to the code in this answer and it worked.

Comment: @Beniamino_Baggins ah ok, fair enough